# How could I import several .so files to Python with for loop?

Tags: python, python-import, python-importlib

So I would like to import several `.so` files which is in a subdirectory, here is the tree

```sh
.
├── driver.py
├── intvegas.f
├── jetdrive-unp-algo.f90
├── jetint-unp-algo.f
├── jetme-unp-algo.f
├── makefile
├── part-unp-ms.f90
├── setup.sh
└── so
    ├── g_g_to_g_g.so
    ├── g_g_to_q_qb.so
    ├── g_q_to_g_q.so
    ├── q_q_to_q_q.so
    ├── q_qb_to_g_g.so
    ├── q_qb_to_q_qb.so
    ├── q_qb_to_qp_qbp.so
    ├── q_qbp_to_q_qbp.so
    ├── q_qp_to_q_qp.so
    └── total.so
```

I would like to import all the `.so` files reside in directory `so`, here is the code

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, os
sys.path.insert(0, './so')
import numpy as np
import pylab as py

channels = {'total', 'q_qp_to_q_qp', 'q_qbp_to_q_qbp', 'q_q_to_q_q', 'q_qb_to_qp_qbp', 'q_qb_to_q_qb', 'q_qb_to_g_g', 'g_g_to_q_qb', 'g_q_to_g_q', 'g_g_to_g_g'}
import importlib
for channel in channels:
    module = './so' + channel
    globals()[module] = importlib.import_module(module, package = 'my_current_package')
```

But I am getting error like following

```sh
ImportError: Import by filename is not supported.
```

Could anyone help me on this issue? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for channel in channels:
    module = './so' + channel
```

Are you sure you are getting the correct filenames in this case?
Perhaps the fix is:

```
module = channel
```

Comment: I am getting `ImportError: No module named so` when using `module = channel + '.so'`.

Comment: I find out! Just use `channel` solely in assigning the value of `module`!

Comment: @zyy Right you are. Sorry I missed out on your initial `sys.path.insert(0, './so')` line